# usage of "after" and "before"

Tags: grammar

The following is an excerpt from [The Guardian of Sept. 8](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2022/sep/08/queen-elizabeth-ii-britains-longest-reigning-monarch-dies-aged-96).

All four of her children 〈had rushed to Balmoral after Buckingham Palace announced〉 in a statement at 13.32pm that she was under medical supervision at Balmoral after her doctors said they were " concerned for her health".

If what happened is Buckingham Palace announced… and then all four of her children rushed to Balmoral, I think the article should read “All of her children rushed to Balmoral 〈after〉 Buckingham Palace had announced … Or, if all four of her children had rushed to Balmoral 〈before〉 Buckingham Palace announced …, it makes sense too.

Would someone help clear up my confusion?

Answer (score 1):

This is the sequence of events, including one from the paragraph preceding the sentence quoted:

1. Doctors said they were concerned for her (i.e. the Queen's) health.
2. Buckingham palace announced in a statement that she (i.e the Queen) was under medical supervision.
3. All four children rushed to Balmoral.
4. The King issued a statement on Thursday evening.

The quoted sentence is speaking in the time frame of (4), so it uses the past perfect to describe an event (3, the children rushing to Balmoral) which was complete and whose result was relevant at time (4).

The other events (1 & 2) were also in the past, but for these "after" makes the sequencing clear so the past perfect isn't needed (you *could* use it but it would make the sentence clumsy with too many "had"s).